# WPF-App not sending events to ApplicationInsights

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, events, azure-application-insights

We have a problem integrating ApplicationInsights into our client server WPF Application:

- Events are not being sent to the azure portal when using the release version of our application.
- All events – client and serversided – are sent successfully when opening the application in debug mode from within Visual Studio (Professional 2017).
- We tested with Firewall and Proxy temporarily letting through all outgoing traffic.
- Windows 8 + .NET 4.5.2 is installed on all machines while the wpf app is targeting .NET 4.0

We have set our proxy to let through traffic according to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-ip-addresses , but as the events are not being received in the Azure Portal when both firewall and proxy are temporarily disabled this isn´t really relevant.

**Does anyone have an idea why the events are not being sent when operating with the release version?**

---

**UPDATE:**

When building a release version of the client in visual studio and running it then, it sends the events(!). Normally the release version is built using Jenkins and MSBuild. Is there a difference?

---

**UPDATE 2:**

There seems to be a connection to the path from which the WPF-App is being started. If the app is located and started from any sub-path of C:\Projects it sends the events to ApplicationInsights, if not it doesn´t. For anyone interested, the code for building up the TelemetryClient is:

```
private static TelemetryClient GetAppInsightsClient() {
    TelemetryClient client = null;
    if (Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() != null) {
        var config = new TelemetryConfiguration();
        config.InstrumentationKey = TelemetryKey;
        config.TelemetryChannel = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel();
        //config.TelemetryChannel = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.InMemoryChannel(); // Default channel
        config.TelemetryChannel.DeveloperMode = Debugger.IsAttached;

#if DEBUG
        config.TelemetryChannel.DeveloperMode = true;
        //debug = true;
#endif

        client = new TelemetryClient(config);
        client.Context.Component.Version = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
        client.Context.Session.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        client.Context.User.Id = (Environment.UserName + Environment.MachineName).GetHashCode().ToString();
        client.Context.Device.OperatingSystem = Environment.OSVersion.ToString();
    }
    return client;
}
```

Comment: Is the InstrumentationKey correctly set in Release Mode?

Comment: yes, it´s implemented as a const and not changed

Comment: any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm not really no. Sorry....

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering anyway :-) Maybe you have an idea concerning my 2nd update?

Comment: Ok, I´ve found the bug. It was a condition in the Telemetry-Class returning the wrong value. So this issue has nothing to do with application insights - it was a programming mistake. Closing the issue now...